# What REALLY defines on and off topic?

Tags: bug, off-topic

So I'm getting fed up of my questions - which I consider to be genuine - getting voted as being Off-Topic, for reasons that don't make sense in comparison to other questions.

For example, my latest question (*[Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour)*) asked for advice on good ways to communicate with specific niche audiences on social networking sites.

In less than 40 minutes my post was flagged for *asking for personal advice on "what to do" without defining a goal* and received -3 votes.

Yet, another question, *How to ask my boyfriend's family if it bothers them that I'm coming along* has been open for 9 months, has 34 up votes and 5 answers. Isn't saying `How to` in the title clearly asking for personal advice?

It seems to me that sometimes if people don't know the answer, or don't feel like answering, they decide to close it and pretend it never existed.

Comment: This would likely be better suited to Interpersonal's Meta site, instead of the generic one for all the sites in the network. It's really up to each site to define what sorts of questions they keep, and those they don't.

Comment: Seems like I'm getting the same treatment here really - 4 downvotes in 8 views, and told it's not suitable for this particular Meta site. If I ask on IPS I'll more than likely get told to ask somewhere else anyway

Comment: I mean, the close reason for the first question you mentioned, ignoring the question body, does seem to be missing a "goal," unless you defined that elsewhere. The one you compared it to does have a clearly defined goal.

Comment: Well...I'm not sure what you expect us to be able to do; your issue is specific to Interpersonal, not generic to the entire network.  Questions need to be asked in the appropriate spaces.

Comment: @W.H.: "*If I ask on IPS I'll more than likely get told to ask somewhere else anyway*" On IPS's meta site? I rather doubt that. But you should not ask the way you did here.

Comment: Just pissed off with every question being held back and more people discussing whether it's on or off topic than trying to answer it

Comment: @W.H.: You are not owed an answer by anyone. If your question does not follow the rules, it gets closed. That's *what rules are for*. The questions people are supposed to be "trying to answer" are the questions that don't break the rules. Just like if you go to a bar and start grabbing random peoples' privates, you will be asked to leave.

Comment: StackExchange sites take a decent amount to get used to.  Unfortunately, the sites themselves don't do a good job of setting those expectations up front, but we still have to enforce the rules.  We're trying to help you; you need to ask this on IPS.  Complaining about it here won't help anybody.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're disappointed in your question being off topic here, but the crowd is right. It is better to ask about what makes a good on topic question on site specific metas as there's no one magic answer. I realize this puts you between a rock and a hard place as you don't yet have the necessary reputation to post on IPS meta though :/ I do see you have overall earned more than 20 reputation, so perhaps you could drop by in the interpersonal skills [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence), there's probably people online that can help you out :)

Comment: Hey W.H! I'm a user over on IPS who saw the 4 questions you've asked (that have now been deleted). It seems each was asking about advice on running your social media-oriented business (ie: "how can I get XXX twitter followers?"). I noticed other users trying to explain to you that IPS is not the place for these kinds of questions--we simply aren't equipped to help you deal with such a broad goal. We tend to focus on specific interpersonal interactions. I'm sorry that you seem to feel alienated at the moment, but if you do have an interpersonal question in the future, we'd love to see you back!

Comment: Part of the problem @scohe001 is that `NSFW` has been misinterpreted as `XXX` on many occasions, making replies irrelevant. NSFW in the posts I have made mean far from pornographic XXX content, rather content that is deemed a little too much for the general audience ( graphic horror art and photography vs commercial horror film clips for example ). Still, it's beyond debating now.

Comment: @W.H. ahh I suppose I chose a poor character for a wildcard there. I'm using "XXX" to mean some large number. I don't recall (or at least wasn't trying to reference) anything NSFW.

Comment: @W.H., did you read the [tour](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour) on any of the Stack Exchange sites you are using? It looks like you didn't (since you dont' have any "informed" badge). I highly recommend reading the tour and the [help section](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help), since they explain how the sites work, how to ask questions, and which topics are on-topic for each specific site.

Answer (score 15):

> Seems to me that sometimes if people don't know the answer, or don't feel like answering, they decide to close it and pretend it never existed.

But that's not what is being said. The off-topic reason for your first question was:

> asking for personal advice on "what to do" without defining a goal

Clearly, that means that on IPS, they *require* that any "what to do" questions must have a goal. That's a requirement that they've laid down on the site, and that's how the site operates. They believe that your question lacks a goal, and therefore is incomplete.

You can agree with it or disagree with it. But those are the rules; you can abide by them, or you can go elsewhere.

If you believe that these rules are incorrect, you can go to IPS's meta site and argue that those rules should be changed. ***However***, before doing so, you should read through the many, *many* meta discussions on their site, so that you can know *why* those rules were imposed. If you go in with the attitude of "these people just don't feel like answering", your interactions will be highly unproductive.

Assume that the people establishing those rules did so for a reason. First, find out what it is, then find a convincing reason why it should be changed, if it should be changed at all.

Comment: I can't show my original post because it was deleted by the admins, but I would have thought the goal was obvious - To communicate with people who were interested in the niche of the social media account that I had created

Comment: @W.H.: I don't know how IPS operates, but that goal seems exceedingly broad. My guess is that they probably want more specific questions. A focused goal would probably be about you wanting to communicate a *specific thing* to that group. IPS probably doesn't want to be about general "how to communicate with group X" questions; they want something specific like "how to communicate idea Y to group X". Such questions are more likely to be informed by experience than just people offering off-the-cuff advice and ideas about what *might* work.

Comment: @NicolBolas for someone that doesn't know how IPS operates, you write very good answers. Your comment above is spot on :)

Comment: @W.H. this sounds like “how do I find an audience for and market my <thing>”, which as Nicolas says is very broad. There is no one right answer or silver bullet, or marketing wouldn’t exist as an entire *industry*.